# Twilio Sync: connection closed by server, reason is TOKEN_EXPIRED

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

Twilio Sync Time out is 172800

```
$.getJSON("/dashboard/token", function (response) {
    console.log(`Token Generated at ${new Date()}`);
    localStorage.setItem('syncToken', response.token);
    
    syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(response.token, { logLevel: "info" });

    syncClient.on('tokenAboutToExpire', function () {
        console.log(`tokenAboutToExpire at: ${new Date()}`);
        var token = localStorage.getItem('syncToken');
        syncClient.updateToken(token);
    });
});
```

Here is the Twilio Sync browser console showing:

```
Twilsock I: socket opened
twilio-sync.js:25304 Twilsock I: refreshing all registrations
twilio-sync.js:25304 Twilsock I: update registration for context 8c430fb3-4353-4b06-9cfd-6bebc78582b0
```

But after some time this message will occurs in browser:

```
Twilsock I: connection has expired
Notify I: Transport ready false 
Twilsock I: connection closed by server, reason is TOKEN_EXPIRED
Twilsock I: socket closed CloseEvent
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve this on Twilio Sync Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I tried all events so here I got it...

```
syncClient.on('connectionStateChanged', (newState) => {
    console.log('Received a new connection state:', newState);
    if (newState === 'disconnecting') {
        $.getJSON("/dashboard/token", function (response) {
            var token = response.token;
            syncClient.updateToken(token);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The event you are receiving there is that the token is about to expire, however you are replacing the token with itself. Instead, you should request a new token from your back-end and update the client with that new token.

```js
$.getJSON("/dashboard/token", function (response) {
    console.log(`Token Generated at ${new Date()}`);
    localStorage.setItem('syncToken', response.token);
    
    syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(response.token, { logLevel: "info" });

    syncClient.on('tokenAboutToExpire', function () {
        console.log(`tokenAboutToExpire at: ${new Date()}`);
        $.getJSON("/dashboard/token", function (response) {
            syncClient.updateToken(response.token);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So, tell me when this "tokenAboutToExpire" event hits on twilio.sync.js file

Comment: As [the documentation says](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/3.0.1/docs/classes/SyncClient.html#tokenAboutToExpire) the `tokenAboutToExpire` event is triggered when your access token is about 3 minutes from expiry. That should give you enough time to fetch a new token and update it.

Comment: Can I change the time out for Twilio Sync Object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you talk about the Twilio Sync Object as I have been discussing the Access Token. You can change the timeout for an Access Token though, by default it is 1 hour (3600 seconds) and can be up to 24 hours. See how to set the `ttl` in the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens#step-2-generate-token

Comment: Its still expire the token and one other thing, TokenAbouttoExpire Event not hit three min before the JWT token expire.

Comment: Have you implemented the change above where you fetch a new token when you receive the expiry event?

Comment: Yes I implemented but event not occurs even the JWT token expired.

Comment: Are you listening for the other [events the client can emit](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/3.0.1/docs/classes/SyncClient.html) too? Like `connectionError`, `connectionStateChanged` and `tokenExpired`? It would be good to understand what is firing here and why, so I'd recommend implementing each of the events and logging when they happen.